# How to override price html on product list page

Tags: magento2, price, product-attribute, list.phtml

> I am writing a custom module for magento 2 i.e "call for price" and I want to override price html on product list page.
>
> I have follow the following scenario:

1.etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Mymodule\Callforprice\Block\Callforprice" />
</config>
```

2.Block/Callforprice.php

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\Callforprice\Block;
/**
 * Product price block
 */
class Callforprice extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox 
{

     /**
     * Wrap with standard required container
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @return string
     */
    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        if($this->getSaleableItem()->getCallforprice()): // getCallforprice() is product attribute
            return '<div class="price-box "><span>Call For Price</span></div>';
        else :
            return '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
                'data-role="priceBox" ' .
                'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
                '>' . $html . '</div>';
        endif;
    }

}
```

> Any suggestion would be appreciated.
>
> Thanks

Comment: If you are developing the `call for price` extension then this link will help you https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-call-for-price

Comment: I have tried this but not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

> **Here price hide when guest user login and price show after customer login.**

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\etc\frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="price_hide" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\HidePriceBox" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin**

**HidePriceBox.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin;

class HidePriceBox
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $session;
    }

    function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $result)
    {   
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vendor/Module/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/price/simple/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/price/configurable/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

As you can see we are overriding 2 templates, for simple and configurable product.

Then add .phtml files in paths configured in xml.

This snippet actually overrides price blocks' templates on product page but you can put it in appropriate layout file.

Comment: You should definitely NOT be modifying anything within Vendor files.

Comment: Dude, it is a placeholder for his vendor name..... you serious?

Comment: Did anyone try this solution, is it working?